# In R, find data frame indeces of multiple columns using custom sort vectors to control ggplot2 plotting

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, r-factor

I would like to control plotting of values in `v3` (in df below) using ggplot2 according to the factor levels (of `v4`), ie. the order of plotting.

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    v1=c("a","b","c","a"),
    v2=c("z", "x", "x", "y"),
    v3=c(1,2,3,4),
    v4=factor(c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4")))

require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=v4,y=v3))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

To change the order of `v4` in the plot comes down to specifying the levels of `v4`. If I would like to plot according to `v1` its straith-forward to change the levels:

```
df$v4 <- with(df,factor(v4, levels= v4[order(df$v1)]))
ggplot(df, aes(x=v4,y=v3))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

And since both "id1" and "id4" have the `v1` value "a" we could choose to resolve this tie by a second vector, say `v2`, in the argument to `order()`:

```
df$v4 <- with(df,factor(v4, levels= v4[order(df$v1, df$v2)]))
ggplot(df, aes(x=v4,y=v3))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")
```

[image]

You can change the "decreasing=F" argument in `order()` to reverse the sort order, but how can you specify a custom order to sort by.  E.g. if you above do not want the alphabetical order of `v1` but rather c>b>a (first c, then b, then a) ? Obviously subsetting using match (along: df[match(c("c","b","a"),df$v1),"v4"]) only works if you have unique values in `v1`. I seem to miss a "by" argument to order() like: order(df$v1, df$v2, by=c(s1,s2)) where "s1" and "s2" are vectors to find the order of `v1`  and `v2` by (in our case "s1" <- c("c", "b", "a")). 
Basically I need to find the indeces of a data frame using more than one variable/column (in our `df`: `v1`, and if ties resolve by `v2`) by using custom sort vectors (in our `df` this is `s1` and `s2`). How can this be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried specifying the levels for v1 using indices and successfully got c>b>a as the order in ggplot2. I put this above your df$v4 <- with(df... and then ran the rest of the code unchanged.

```
df$v1 <- factor(df$v1,
                levels(df$v1)[c(3,2,1,4)])
```